# cmake targets from find_package are not propagated to siblings

Tags: cmake

I am unsure about the scope of a cmake target added in a subdirectory. I created the following structure

```
|---root
|   main_which_uses_lib2.cpp
|   CMakeLists.txt
|---|---first child
|       CMakeLists.txt
|       sourcefile_for_lib1.cpp
|---|---second child
|       CMakeLists.txt
|       sourcefile_for_lib2_which_uses_lib1.cpp
```

second child library references first child library. main uses second child library. Both libraries are added to main through main directory via

```
add_subdirectory
```

This compiles fine. Does it do that by design or by coincidence? I am working on another project where the CMakeLists.txt of lib1 calls find_package. find_package creates several targets which are not propagated to lib2. The setup causes errors in the cmake setup. More specifically, it populates the interface definitions with generator expressions like the following

```
INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "\$<TARGET_PROPERTY:torch_cpu,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>"
```

I link against the corresponding libraries in lib1 publicly, e.g. via

```
target_link_libraries(lib1 PUBLIC ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})
```

which means everything that is in the interface libraries/compile definitions/include directories of ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} should be used by anything that uses target_link_libraries on lib1. While the definitions do carry over to lib2, the targets are gone: I get an error message like

```
torch_cpu is not a target.
```

Variables in cmake generally have a local scope, however targets seem to work differently.

I did not find an explanation for this behaviour and would appreciate any input

Comment: In some cases the scope of cmake targets is not global among others one that's likely to be used in a cmake configuration script, see the [documentation for `add_library(... IMPORTED)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries)

Comment: "The setup causes errors in the cmake setup." - This is very **vague** description of the problem, which could mean many things. E.g. 1. `lib2/CMakeLists.txt` directly uses results of `find_package` called `lib1/CMakeLists.txt` 2. `lib2/CMakeLists.txt` links with `lib1` target, but that linkage behaves wrongly. Stack Overflow is not a place for *guesses*. Please, prepare [mcve].

Comment: Probably, `torch_cpu` is an IMPORTED target, which has local visibility: it is visible only in `lib1/CMakeLists.txt` but not in main `CMakeLists.txt` and not in `lib2/CMakeLists.txt`. Why do you ever sets `INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` to the generator expression, involved same property but for another target (`torch_cpu`)? Normally, a libraries linkage is used for the property propagation, like `target_link_libraries(lib1 PUBLIC torch_cpu)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't directly. The torch config does (not written by me, but the torch guys, which means I have little control over it). Big thanks for the hint on imported targets.

Comment: Ok, I remembered such weird things about Torch and their Find(Config) script. Fast googling revealed [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084656/cmake-cant-find-the-external-libraries-when-subdirectory-is-used-to-build-depend) about similar (or same) problems. It still has no answer/solution.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are correct, it is the same mistake. Marking this as duplicate.